# removing space between 2 consecutive paragraphs

Tags: html, css, email

I am creating an html email and testing it in Entourage for Mac. How does one remove the white space between 2 consecutive paragraphs . I tried the following , it works in every mail client except Gmail and Entourage :(

```
<p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; 
          font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; 
          margin:0; padding:0; margin-top: 1cm; text-align: left;">
Exhibit Space Sales are Open to All</p>
<p style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; 
          font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  text-align: left; 
          margin-bottom: 1cm; padding:0;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 
text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 
survived not only five centuries</p>
```

Any help would be appreaciated

Comment: What happens if you try explicitly setting `margin-bottom: 0` on the top paragraph and `margin-top: 0` on the bottom paragraph? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Why are you using CM as your measurement? Why not PX?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add 'margin-top:-0.5em' to the 2nd paragraph style.

Another would be to use `<DIV> instead of <P>`

Comment: I cannot use div because its an html email. So best practices dictate using tables instead of div :(

Comment: @user121 There are so many things wrong with that last sentence.

Comment: I am trying to create it using only tables and paragraphs. Hence I have an issue with the space between 2 paragraphs. I can remove the space using p{   padding:0; margin:0; }. But in that case I am unable to include the margin-top and margin-bottom attributes. The moment i include them, the space is created between the 2 paragraphs

Comment: I'm curious which "best practices" recommend not using divs?

Answer (score 0):

They are right. Unlike developing for browsers, emails are a pain to code for since you have to use elementary HTML and inline CSS for EVERYTHING. You can't even use padding since most versions of outlook dont recognize it.